# Refresh Listview of another fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm Using viewpager with 2 swiping tab layouts. In the first tablayout I post data to the server and when I switch the tab the Listview in not update. Only when I click on Listview Item and close it the Listview gets refreshed and the posted data is visible...
Question Is : How to automatically refresh Listview when data is posted to server can some one help please.

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int numOfTabs;
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,int numOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.numOfTabs=numOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            RaiseComplaintFragment RFragment=new RaiseComplaintFragment();
            return RFragment;
        case 1:
            ComplaintListFragment CFragment=new ComplaintListFragment();
            return CFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numOfTabs;
}
```

}

This is the method which posts data to the server

```
 public void postDataToServer(String complaintdata) throws JSONException {
    String url = URLMap.getPostComplaintUrl();

    String roleId = LoggedInUserStore.getLoggedInRoleId(getContext());
    String branchId = LoggedInUserStore.getLoggedInBranchId(getContext());
    String compid = LoggedInUserStore.getLoggedInCompanyId(getContext());

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("CallRecordID", "0"); //pass 0 if we are inserting a new record always
    params.put("CompanyID", compid);
    params.put("BranchID", branchId);
    params.put("ServiceID", sId);
    params.put("CallLocationID", lId);
    params.put("RaisedByID", roleId);
    params.put("ComplaintDetails", complaintdata);
    params.put("CallStatusID", "1");
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
    pDialog.setProgressStyle(pDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Complaint has been registered successfully");
            builder.setMessage("").setCancelable(true);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            _complaintText.setText("");
            serviceSpinner.setSelection(0);
            locationSpinner.setSelection(0);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            /*((HomeActivity)getActivity()).getViewPager().setCurrentItem(1);  //onCLick of Submit it just switches the tab
            String tagName="android:switcher:"+R.id.pager+":"+1;
            ComplaintListFragment f2=(ComplaintListFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tagName);
            f2.fetchComplaintData();*/
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Unable to register your request.\nPlease try later.");
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    req.setRetryPolicy(new VolleyRetryPolicy().getRetryPolicy());
    RequestQueue requestQueue = ((VolleyRequestQueue) getActivity().getApplication()).getRequestQueue();
    requestQueue.add(req);
}
```

My HomeActivity class which handles two tab layouts

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_Pager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_Layout);


    String roleID = LoggedInUserStore.getLoggedInRoleId(getApplicationContext());
    if (roleID.equals("4")) {

        //RAISE COMPLAINT UI. IF ROLE ID == 4 MANAGER DASHBOARD

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Raise Complaint"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Complaint List"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final PagerAdapter adapter =
                new com.six30labs.cms.adapters.PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Second fragment which contains my listview

```
public class ComplaintListFragment extends Fragment {
private ListView complaintListView;
EditText _inputSearch;
ComplaintAdapter compadapter;
private static Parcelable mListViewScrollPos = null;
private RequestQueue mQueue;
ProgressBar progressBar;
String URL;
private View v;
String TAG="Second Fragment";


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_complaint_list, container, false);
    complaintListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.complaintListView);
    _inputSearch = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.inputSearchforComplaintListFragment);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.complaintListProgressBar);

    fetchComplaintData();

    _inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try {
                compadapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                compadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    if (mListViewScrollPos != null) {
        complaintListView.onRestoreInstanceState(mListViewScrollPos);
    }

    return v;
}

public void fetchComplaintData() {

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     URL = URLMap.getComplaintUrl("complaint_url");
    URL = URL.replace("{id}", LoggedInUserStore.getLoggedInCompanyId(getContext()));


    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            getCompliantList(response);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    request.setRetryPolicy(new VolleyRetryPolicy().getRetryPolicy());
    RequestQueue queue=((VolleyRequestQueue)getActivity().getApplication()).getRequestQueue();
    queue.add(request);
   /* RequestQueue requestQueue
   = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(request);*/
}

public void getCompliantList(String response) {

    try {
        List complaint = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
```

//                complaint.add(Complaint.fromJson(jArray.getJSONObject(i)));

```
            complaint.add(0,Complaint.fromJson(jArray.getJSONObject(i))); //To push the data to the top of the listview.
        }
        compadapter = new ComplaintAdapter(getContext(), complaint);
        complaintListView.setAdapter(compadapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Method that will save the position the user when they scroll
//return it when the user comes back to the listView instead of it refreshing the data.
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mListViewScrollPos = complaintListView.onSaveInstanceState();
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    fetchComplaintData();
}
```

Comment: Make that method public static or use interface. Also use broadcast receiver.

Comment: use interface to refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BroadcastReceiver` For class **Where your Listview is**

```
private BroadcastReceiver updateProfileBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Fire your event
    }
};
```

Register **Broadcast** in `onResume()`

```
registerReceiver(updateProfileBroadcast, new IntentFilter("KEY"));
```

Now fire **Broadcast** From **Fragment**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("KEY");
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: My Listview is in another Fragment Sir...ComplaintListFragment I have update the code...

Comment: Yes It will work. Do one thing. create and register Broasdcast in fragment which has listview and Fire broadcast from another fragment. Refresh listview inside onReceive.

Comment: Yes, you should use BroadcastReceivers.

Comment: @SID : Thanks for your answer. I have implemented using Broadcast..But I have a different scenario In my other fragments(say xyzfragment) I'm showing up a listview and onclick of listview I'm firing an activity and this activity contains details of listview & post method. After I post data to server I want to refresh Listview which is in other fragment. How to achieve this?

Comment: If your fragment is live then the same will be use no problem will occur.

Comment: Would be great f it was a little more understandable with additional explanation

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to SID's answer you may use [`EventBus`](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). It works by event-driven architecture and able to transfer information between components really easy and fast.

That's how you use it:

1) add to project in app gradle: `compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'`

2) Register `EventBus` in fragment's `onCreate()` where you need to update `ListView`: `eventBus.register(this);`. And don't forget to unregister it on `onDestryView()`: `eventBus.unregister(this);`

3) Add the method to your `ListView` fragment which will handle event with list update:

```
@SupressWarning("unused")
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(List<YourListViewData> event) {/* update `ListView` */};
```

4) Fire that event from activity\fragment when you need to update `ListView`:

```
EventBus bus = EventBus.getInstance();
eventBus.post(List<YourListViewData> yourData);
```